# Use nginx as proxy for websocket connection

Tags: nginx, websocket

How do I use nginx as proxy for a websocket ?
If I need to connect to socketSite.com:port from clientSite.com( javascript)
And I won't to show user's link "socketSite.com:port "

Can I use nginx proxy for redirecting requests from/to websocket server ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely, you can! Use the following configuration:

```
location /myHandler{
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X_Forwarded_For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8880;
    proxy_redirect default;
    client_max_body_size 1000m;
}
```

I use spring websocket. `/myHandler` is my URL to create the websocket connection, `http://localhost:8880;` is my Tomcat server address. Nginx server and Tomcat are running on the same machine.